# get the percentage value of a div id value in javascript

Tags: javascript

I get the values into div where id is totAmount

```
    <div id="totAmount"><input type="text" value="" name="total" id="amount"     class="input-block-level" autocomplete="off"  required/></td></div>
```

I called to myFunction here to get the percentage values.

```
    <input type="text" value="" onKeyUp = "myFunction(this)" name="'. $target['week'] . '" id="'. $target['week'] . '_percentage"  class="input-block-level" autocomplete="off"  required/>
```

Here this is myFunction.I can get the div id value.but percentage calculation doesn't work.

```
function myFunction(element){
       var v1 = document.getElementById("totAmount").innerHTML;
       var percentage = parseInt(v1) *  parseInt(v2) / 100;
       alert(percentage);

       var idString = element.getAttribute("id");
       var amountId = idString.substr(0, idString.indexOf('_')) + '_amount'

       document.getElementById(amountId).value = percentage;
       var percent = document.getElementById(amountId).value;

       percentAmounts.push(percent);
       percentValues.push(v2);

    }
```

Comment: Where are you defining v2 and what is the value of v2?

Comment: What do you mean by "percentage"? Percentage of what?

Comment: Where is v2 coming from?

Comment: Its unclear as if what is not working exactly, percentage calculation doesn't work,  etc. what's your problem exactly?

Comment: I want to get the div id value into javascript variable.It works.I want to divide that value according to the percentages I'm giving.but it doesn't work?

Comment: Does this help?
var v1 = document.getElementById("amount").innerHTML;  I can't see where you are getting v2 from.

Comment: yes I made a big mistake there.Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is you value two coming from, assuming that its from the second `input` where you have set `onKeyUp`, modify your code as below to add the value for `v2`,

```
var v1 = document.getElementById("totAmount").innerHTML;
var v2 = element.value;
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: yes that's my mistake.I totally missed it.Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You've got some weird and wrong stuff in there with the "" and whatnot.  I think your percentage issue is just a math error, though it's tough to tell from the description.  If you want to know what percent something is of something else, you divide one by the other, then multiply by 100.  So your equation should be:

```
var percentage = (parseInt(v1) /  parseInt(v2)) * 100;
```

I'll see if I can figure out the rest....there's too much unknown here for me to iron it out.  Your HTML is being generated from some other language using "." to concatenate, maybe Python?  In javascript, you use "+".  I can't figure out how you're using "$target['week']".  Anyway, I did a jsfiddle trying to understand what you're trying to do.  Here it is, in case it helps:

https://jsfiddle.net/mw2qu8w0/

Answer (score 0):

I don't konw what "v2" is. But obviously the "v1" is NaN, is just the innerHTML of a dom object. You can use :

```
var v1=document.getElementById("totAmount").getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value
```

to get the value of the input which you may need.